# When rows of data are copied to new location, data is copied correctly, but blank rows are inserted between data rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA.

In multiple locations on sheets in a workbook, I have 4 columns of data.  They are not always in the same columns, and the range can begin on different rows.  The first row always contains the same headings (ID, Description, Times, Category).  The data in Column 3 (Times) of the range is always a number.  What I am attempting to achieve is to copy each row in the data range I select to a new location the number of times indicated in column 3 (rows with a '0' value are copied once).

I have an input box to select the range I want to copy, and an input box to select the cell where I would like to begin copying the data to.

The code I have written seems to work perfectly if the destination to copy to begins in row 1.  If my destination begins in any other row, the information is copied correctly, but blank rows are inserted between every row of copied data.  The number of blank rows varies and seems to be contingent on the row assigned to begin copying the output data to (IE. if output beings in row 2 - 1 blank row is inserted between each data row; if output begins in row 3 - 2 blank rows inserted between each data row; if output begins in row 4 - 3 blank rows inserted between data rows etc.).

Typically there will be data in the columns on either side of my output destination, and data in these columns can be in rows above or below my output destination as well. (IE. if my output destination is F4:I10, there may already be data present in A1:D7 and K9:L34)  This does not seem to be an issue in the code I have written, but I have mentioned it as it may impact suggested solutions.

An example of my data and desired output is:

[image: Image of Selected Data and Desired Output]

Here is the code I have been working with.

```
Sub expandedcopy()

Dim source As Range
Dim destination As Range
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastblankrow As Long



Set source = Application.InputBox("Select the entire table (including headers) to extrapolate", Type:=8)

Set destination = Application.InputBox("Select the upper-left cell location to which your data will be coppied.  4 rows to the right are required", Type:=8)

destination.Offset(0, 0).Value = "ID"
destination.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Description"
destination.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Times"
destination.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Category"
StartRow = 2
usedRowsSrc = source.Rows.Count - 1

For i = StartRow To usedRowsSrc
  strID = source.Cells(i, 1).Value
  strDescription = source.Cells(i, 2).Value
  strTimes = source.Cells(i, 3).Value
  strCategory = source.Cells(i, 4).Value
  iTimes = source.Cells(i, 3).Value + 1

Set ws = destination.Worksheet

ws.Activate

  For j = 1 To iTimes
    lastblankrow = Cells(Rows.Count, destination.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    With destination
      .Offset(lastblankrow, 0).Value = strID
      .Offset(lastblankrow, 1).Value = strDescription
      .Offset(lastblankrow, 2).Value = strTimes
      .Offset(lastblankrow, 3).Value = strCategory
    End With
  Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are offsetting the same number of rows as the last used row. So if you start at row 3, lastblankrow=3 and your offsets will go up by 3. You just need to find the last row and increment by 1 each time.

Comment: First thing I noticed was a newbie error: you omitted the ***Option Explicit***. Read up on that before you build up errors

Comment: Thanks.  I'll familiarize myself with Option Explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach, in which each row is copied altogether the requisite number of times.

```
Sub expandedcopy()

Dim source As Range, destination As Range, i As Long, j As Long, n As Long

Set source = Application.InputBox("Select the entire table (including headers) to extrapolate", Type:=8)
Set destination = Application.InputBox("Select the upper-left cell location to which your data will be coppied.  4 rows to the right are required", Type:=8)

destination.Resize(, source.Columns.Count).Value = source.Rows(1).Value
j = 1

For i = 2 To source.Rows.Count
    n = source.Cells(i, 3).Value + Abs(source.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0)
    source.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 4).Copy destination.Resize(n).Offset(j)
    j = j + n
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I ran the code and it copied the first line the appropriate number of times and then a "run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" message occurred.  When I went to debug, the following line was highlighted.  "source.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 4).Copy destination.Resize(source.Cells(i, 3).Value).Offset(j)"  Thanks again for any insights.

Comment: Do you have any rows with nothing or text in the third column?

Comment: The only text is in the 'header' row and there are no blank cells in the third column.  After seeing your comment, I looked at the data I was trying to copy, and the 2nd value in column 3 was '0'.  I changed the '0' to '1' and the code ran correctly until it hit another '0' value in column 3.  When there is a '0' value in column 3, I need it to be copied to the new location once.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks so much.